# What is the difference between "docker images ls" and "docker image ls"?

Tags: docker, server

What is the difference between `docker images ls` and `docker image ls` (with and without **s** (plural form))?

I'm confused about these two commands in Docker. `docker images ls` is listing images in docker, what is the purpose of `docker image ls` command?

Check the docs:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_ls/
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/

Comment: For me `docker images ls` returns an empty list, while `docker image ls` returns a list with several images. Maybe "ls" is filtering so only results that contain "ls" show up? (none of mine contain it)

Comment: in simple words "docker images" command is equal to "docker image ls" , so you should get same out put as "docker image ls" for command "docker images" (without ls images not image)

Comment: According to https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/887#issuecomment-366654909, `docker image ls` is to be preferred over `docker images`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`docker images list` is not an alias to `docker image list`, `docker images` is. When calling `docker images list`, it's the same as `docker image list list` or `docker image list --filter=reference=list`, which means filtering the image list with reference that are equal to list — and as you don't have any images containing list, it's returning an empty list. (Read this github discussion by vdemeester and many more https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/887 )

However, when you do `docker images image_name`, what it does is, it returns all the parameters(list) of image `image_name` i.e.

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
```

Earlier you were trying to have `docker images ls` which means `docker image ls ls` and the second ls is a list and not an image. Hence if you do `docker images` it will list down all the images which means it is `docker image ls` or `docker image list`. I hope this makes it clear.

Answer (score 7):

- `docker image ls` lists images
- `docker images xyz` lists images with the name `xyz`. So you usually get empty list for a `docker images ls`, because `ls` is treated as name. By the way, we can use a wildcard `docker images postgr*` . Reference: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#list-images-by-name-and-tag

Well, yes, confusing :)

Comment: Also, `docker image ls postgr*` is possible for wildcards )