# How do I inspect the stopped docker container files

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Step 1:

`docker ps -a`

`container Id: dd5cf6b519b4`

I need to inspect inside the stopped docker container which is cannot start.

I tried with `docker exec -it container-id bin/bash` But this is for running container.

Comment: you can use docker log https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to see the files and folders path. In docker logs i am not getting the information.

Comment: then you can use volume to  persisting data generated by and used by Docker containers.

Comment: I am not using any volume configurations. This is for Api deployment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can start container with specific entrypoint

```
docker run --entrypoint sleep YOUR_IMAGE 3600
```

It will block current terminal for 3600 seconds. You can open new terminal tab(do not close current one) and you can verify if your container is working with the

```
docker ps
```

If you do not want to block current terminal, you can add `-d` flag to docker run:

```
docker run -d --entrypoint sleep YOUR_IMAGE 3600
```

Above command will start docker which will be doing nothing, then you can ssh into the container when it is working with

```
docker exec -ti CONTAINER HASH sh
```

Comment: docker run --entrypoint sleep <my image> 3600  
     
This command is not starting my container.

Comment: Ahh so your container is working. You can open a new terminal tab and verify it with `docker ps`. 

Then in new tab you can do `docker exec ...`. From the sleep command you do not see any logs because the `sleep 3600` does not return any output. It just waiting 1 hour. 

I have updated answer to claer it.

Answer (score 11):

```
$ docker ps -a

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE   COMMAND     CREATED         STATUS                    NAMES
0dfd54557799   ubuntu  "/bin/bash" 25 seconds ago  Exited (1) 4 seconds ago  peaceful_feynman

Commit the stopped image
$ docker commit 0dfd54557799 debug/ubuntu

now we have a new image
$ docker images
REPOSITORY    TAG     IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE  
debug/ubuntu  <none>  cc9db32dcc2d   2 seconds ago   64.3MB

create a new container from the "broken" image
$ docker run -it --rm --entrypoint sh debug/ubuntu


inside of the container we can inspect - for example, the file system
$ ls /app    
App.dll
App.pdb
App.deps.json
```

Comment: using `docker commit` to create a new image of an exited container is a helpful hint :-) Thanks!

Comment: Use `docker images` (== `docker image list`) to show the new image, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59640012/1480587